# Should Lifecycle.removeObserver be called in Activity? - Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am finding clear answer with LifecycleObserver.

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity(), LifecycleObserver {
    override fun onCreate() {
       ...
       this.lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }
}
```

In this situation, should I call removeObserver(this) at onDestroy() ?
I think it is not necessary, but I couldn't sure it.

I want an official document or real library code, not just opinion.

Answer (score 2):

No you don't need to call `removeObserver()`.

It's surprisingly difficult to find anything about this in the docs. There is an [Issue about this](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-lifecycles/issues/5) in the repo for the code lab for Lifecycles, where someone asks:

> Here, there is addObserver() call, but there is no removeObserver() call for onDestroy. Is this intentional?

And Jose Alcerreca (an Android Developer Relations Engineer at Google) says:

> Yes, that's the whole point of the new lifecycle-aware components, no need to unsubscribe/remove observers.

Comment: The comment doesn't explain reason.
Could you explain the why removeObserver() isn't needed?

Comment: I'm not sure, but a direct answer from an Android Dev Rel engineer is as good as documentation. It's strange that it's not needed to be sure, but apparently it is not needed.

Comment: Begs the question... why is there a public `removeObserver` method?

Comment: probably to get yourself unregistered much before activity destroy?